# When does the atime of a directory in linux change?

Tags: linux

The atime of a directory doesn't change when I access it using the ls command.
So what does the atime of a directory in Linux mean?
And when does it change?

Comment: Have the filesystem been mounted with the `noatime` or `nodiratime` flags?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure. How can I know that?

Comment: Use the `mount` command to check flags.

Comment: @Some None of the flags have the filesystem been mounted with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The atime of a directory is the last time the directory was "read" to see what files are in it. And when does it change? Just what you thought: when you do things like run `ls`.

So why didn't the atime change when you tried running `ls` in a directory?

As the comments mention, if the filesystem was mounted with `noatime` or `nodiratime` flags, then the atime will not be updated. This is a performance optimization. But you also commented that your filesystem was not mounted with `noatime` or `nodiratime`.

I'm guessing your mount flags might have included `relatime`. That's a common one. It is also added for performance, but rather than completely avoiding updates to atime, it *reduces* how frequently those updates are made.

When your filesystem is mounted with `relatime`, and you read a file or directory, the atime is only updated **if**

1. the atime is older than the ctime (change time) or mtime (modification time), or
2. if the atime is more than a day in the past.

That is *probably* why the atime was not updated in the case you mentioned.